# Sorting of ArrayList using Comparator in Java

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator, collator

I am having an issue with sorting an ArrayList with Ascending order.I am using Comparator and Collator Of Collection class .How can I achieve expected sorting order ? Help is much appreciated.

Ascending order calculated by Algorithm is :

```
[AutomationRejectNotification|,AutomationRejectNotification1011, AutomationRejectNotification1021,AutomationTestNotification1, AutomationTestNotification100,AutomationTestNotification2,testDisplay Template, Testing Chrome, Testing Field, Test Notfication, testnotif, Test Notification #1]
```

Expected Ascending Sorting order is:

```
[AutomationRejectNotification1011, AutomationRejectNotification1021, AutomationRejectNotification|,AutomationTestNotification1, AutomationTestNotification2,AutomationTestNotification100,Test Notfication, Test Notification #1, testDisplay Template, Testing Chrome, Testing Field, testnotif]
```

Java code:

```
public static void listSort(List<String> o1, boolean order) {
        final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\d+");
        Comparator<String> c = new Comparator<String>() {
            public int compare(String object1, String object2) {
                Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);
                Matcher m = p.matcher(object1);

                if (!m.find()) {
                    return collator.compare(object1, object2);
                } else {
                    Long number2 = null;
                    Long number1 = Long.parseLong(m.group());

                    m = p.matcher(object2);
                    if (!m.find()) {
                        return collator.compare(object1, object2);
                    } else {

                        number2 = Long.parseLong(m.group());

                        int comparison = number1.compareTo(number2);
                        if (comparison != 0) {
                            return comparison;
                        } else {
                            return collator.compare(object1, object2);
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
        };
        o1.sort(c);
```

Comment: That's the way Collator works. Take a look at this article: https://documentation.progress.com/output/Corticon/5.3.2/suite_prototype/rfi1341263753418.html

Comment: No, @WinterN, it is *not* how `Collator` works.  Note in particular that in the US locale, the `|` character comes *after* the decimal digits, so `"AutomationRejectNotification|"` collates after `"AutomationRejectNotification1011"`, contrary to the ordering reported by the OP.

Comment: @kaps - rather than providing a single example of your expected output, can you specify the sorting rule that would apply to an arbitrary input list?

Answer (score 2):

Your `Comparator` does not properly implement the contract of the `Comparator` interface, so all bets are off.  The `compare()` method must have all of these properties:

> `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` for all x and y.

> `((compare(x, y)>0) && (compare(y, z)>0))` implies `compare(x, z)>0`.

> `compare(x, y)==0` implies that `sgn(compare(x, z))==sgn(compare(y, z))` for all z.

([API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-))

When both strings being compared contain a non-empty decimal digit sequence, you compare *only* by the numbers, whereas if at least one string is without any digits then you compare via the collator.  That produces these results:

```
compare("z1", "y") > 0

compare("y", "x3") > 0

compare("z1", "x3") < 0
```

, which do not conform to the second required property (transitivity).

Possibly what you want to do is is compare the longest leading digitless substrings as a first criterion, breaking any ties by comparing the trailing numbers, if any.  That might look like this:

```
public static void listSort(List<String> o1, boolean order) {
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^0-9]*)([0-9]+)?");
    final Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);
    Comparator<String> c = new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String object1, String object2) {
            Matcher m1 = p.matcher(object1);
            Matcher m2 = p.matcher(object2);

            if (!m1.lookingAt() || !m2.lookingAt()) {
                assert false : "Should never happen";
            }

            int result = collator.compare(m1.group(1), m2.group(1));

            if (result == 0) {
                String digits1 = m1.group(2);
                String digits2 = m2.group(2);

                if (digits1 != null && digits2 != null) {
                    Long number1 = Long.valueOf(digits1);
                    Long number2 = Long.valueOf(digits2);
                    result = number1.compareTo(number2);
                } else if (digits1 != null) {
                    result = 1;
                } else if (digits2 != null) {
                    result = -1;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    };
    o1.sort(c);
}
```

That would be consistent with the expected order you presented, but there are other ordering schemes that would also produce the same result for those particular elements.

Comment: Hi @John Bollinger : Thanks for your inputs . It throws below error .java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Test-AutomationTestNotification"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
  at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
  at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:803)

Comment: I have all special characters in some of the test data. i.e Test Motification #1,Test Motifcaiotn@34

Comment: @kaps, I suspect you could have troubleshot that problem yourself, but nevertheless, I have fixed it.